# django.contrib.auth utf-8 ascii python 'Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing'

Tags: python, django, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I have a Django web project that was originally authored on a Linux machine (UTF-8) and I cloned the git repository code to my windows machine.   When accessing Django's admin interface running from the built-in development web server, I am unable to authenticate. After running a few of the authentication calls from the Django shell it appears there is an encoding issue.  Yes, I know the best solution would be not to use Microsoft Windows, but this is the development environment my company has provided / decided for me.

Unfortunately, adding this to my settings file does not work on windows:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'UTF-8')
```

From VS 2013 PTVS version 2.2 Immediate Window C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py:

```
user.set_password('mark')
None
user.save()
None
user.check_password('mark')
True
user.check_password('mark')
error: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
user.password
u'bc$$2b$12$FaJjXbx.DupiSJvLJbGg7.YLDd6Ci8wS9BdASm0z94SRttMb.MFwO'
```

You can work around Unicode issue by converting password hash  and the password variable string to ASCII:

```
password = password.encode('ascii')
None
user.check_password(password)
True
```

Clearly this is the wrong approach and I would rather set the default encoding to 'UTF-8' for Python running this Django project globally.

How might I best solve this?

Note: Creating new django projects locally on windows machine work just fine because they are in default ASCII encoding. Also, sys.setdefaultencoding is no longer an option... it would likely cause more problems anyway.  I don't have time to upgrade all our apps to Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the implementation of bcrypt in Django package django-bcrypt==0.9.2, was not coded properly.  I worked around issue by:

1. I removed django_bcrypt Django app from settings.py file:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = ( ...
   # django_bcrypt,
   ...)
   ```
2. I then added this to the settings.py:

   ```
   FILE_CHARSET='UTF-8'
   ```
3. I then simply reset my admin user's password in order to re-hash password using Django's default hash algorithm.

   ```
   python manage.py changepassword *username*
   ```

Now I am able to authenticate on to the local development server again using my windows workstation.  I am sure there is another work around to get bcrypt working with Django, but I only needed this to work on my workstation for development and testing.